# How to get the SHA1 Fingerprint from Mavericks

Tags: android, eclipse, md5, sha1

I am new to developing android apps. I am currently attempting to incorporate some Google maps into my android app. I initially thought I needed the MD5 fingerprint (watching older tutorials) and now I realize that that was for APIv1.  I apparently need the SHA1 fingerprint. Can you get this via Eclipse? Does any one know how? Or the terminal command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the [Google doc](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#installedapplications) :

```
keytool -exportcert -alias keystorealias -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v
```

(key tool is in your `<java-sdk>/bin` folder

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias alias-name -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v
```

So for the android debug.keystore the command should be like this (default password is "android"):

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v
```

The output should be something like this:
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 05:08:81:C5:7F:B7:EA:DA:......